# Replace string with same amount of white spaces in search pattern

Tags: python, regex

I would like to keep the same amount of white space in my string but replace 'no' with empty string. Here is my code:

```
>>> import re
>>> line = '         no command'            
>>> line = re.sub('^\s.+no','',line) 
>>> line
' command'
```

Expected output without only 'no' replaced with empty string and the number of white spaces remain:

```
'         command'
```

Comment: Capture the spaces in a group and use that group in the replacement `line = re.sub('^(\s+)no',r'\1',line) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.+` matches any character, so if you only want to match 1 or more whitespace characters you should repeat `\s+` instead.

Then capture that in group 1 to be able to use that in the replacement and match `no` followed by a word boundary.

Note that `\s` can also match a newline.

```
import re

line = '         no command'
line = re.sub(r'^(\s+)no\b', r'\1', line)
print(line)
```

Output

`command`

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a [positive look behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups). It doesn't quite do exactly what your code does in terms of finding a match at the beginning of the line, but hopefully this sets you on the right track.

```
>>> line = '         no command'
>>> re.sub('(?<=\s)no','',line)
'          command'
```

You can also capture the preceding text.

```
>>> re.sub('^(\s.+)no', r'\1', line)
'          command'
```

Answer (score 1):

what about using the replace method of the string class?

```
new_line = line.replace("no", "")
```